# Sending Ping at fixed packet size as jumbo frame is not working in linux

Tags: linux, ping, icmp, jumboframes

I have to hosts connected each other with ipv4 address each other. I modified the MTU of each one to 9000. Then I want to send a Ping request at fixed packet size +1500 to verify that can send and receive jumbo frames.

When I send the normal ping I get reply as expected but with -s "8972" flag I did not get neither timeout nor reply. I got 100% loss

I made a little environment in mininet to share in here my problem. 
I have modifed both MTU hosts to 9000. These are my commands in mininet:

```
mininet> h1 ifconfig h1-eth0
h1-eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 06:49:45:e2:7e:18  
          Direc. inet:10.0.0.1  Difus.:10.255.255.255  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::449:45ff:fee2:7e18/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:90    </code>00  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:295 errores:0 perdidos:27 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:36 errores:0 perdidos:20 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:67960 (67.9 KB)  TX bytes:11499 (11.4 KB)

mininet> h2 ifconfig h2-eth0
h2-eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 2e:96:2a:84:5f:88  
          Direc. inet:10.0.0.2  Difus.:10.255.255.255  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::2c96:2aff:fe84:5f88/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:304 errores:0 perdidos:28 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:33 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:70325 (70.3 KB)  TX bytes:6954 (6.9 KB)

mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.41 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.386 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.386/1.399/2.412/1.013 ms

mininet> h1 ping -d -v -M "do" -s 1473 -c 3 h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 1473(1501) bytes of data.
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2017ms


mininet> h1 ping -d -v -M "do" -s 1472 -c 3 h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
1480 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.65 ms
1480 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.419 ms
1480 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.089/1.055/2.657/1.140 ms



<code>
mininet> h1 ping -M "do" -s 8972 -c 3 h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 8972(9000) bytes of data.
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
</code>
```

Comment: Your switches must support jumbo frames and be configured with it. Furthermore, you probably do not need jumbo frames at all.

Comment: I need to test that actually jumbo frame feature is working. Then I have enabled jumbo frames in the switch with `ip-mtu` and `max frame size`. I do not know why this is not working even in mininet.